# Pasting copied oleobject to new sheet in the same location

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a function that creates a new version of an entire sheet while archiving the old version. So far it's working but I'm having difficulties with the layout of the oleobjects. Essentially, they are all pasting to the new sheet in various different symptoms of not-right.

I would like to try to find a way to paste the copied object into the same location on the new sheet as the copied object was on the old sheet.

The copy button procedure is pretty self-contained so here it is in its entirety. (Code now Updated)

```
  Sub CopyButton(Button As OLEObject, Sht As Worksheet)
Dim NewButton As OLEObject
Dim newButtonName As String


newButtonName = Button.Name
Set NewButton = Button.Duplicate
'With NewButton
'    .TopLeftCell = Sht.Range(Button.TopLeftCell.Address)
'    .Name = Button.Name
'    .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
'End With
NewButton.Cut
With Sht
   .Paste
    .OLEObjects(.OLEObjects.Count).Name = newButtonName
    .OLEObjects(newButtonName).Activate
    .OLEObjects(newButtonName).Placement = xlMoveAndSize
    .OLEObjects(newButtonName).TopLeftCell = .Range(Button.TopLeftCell.Address)
End With
End Sub
```

I may not need all of that and will work on cleaning things up once I have the functionality I'm looking for. I thought the .Top (being the offset of the object from cell A1 according to the MS help article) would help, but it didn't really help at all.

Essentially I'm trying to make it so if the original button was embedded in Cell D10 of the original sheet, the NewButton will be embedded in Cell D10 of Sht.

Does anyone have any ideas?

This is now updated with the ideas presented so far. Here's the general functional update.

When the current code is replaced with the commented code, the button is duplicated in the source worksheet (the one I'm copying from) and then fails when I try to set the TopLeftCell to Sht.Range (Range method of sht object failed as object is not found)

When the current code is used, the paste job works, but the top left cell address doesn't seem to actually change the coordinates of where the button is located.

Removed extra attempted code and cleaning up attempts for one of the below answers.

I found an answer That seemed to work for me. See below.

Comment: The button should have a `TopLeftCell` property, which returns a range object. You should be able to use that.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't seem to make a difference (tried it in place of .Top and in addition to .Top)

Comment: ok so it looks like it may be in the .Paste(destination) that I need to put my local range. However every range object I can take off of the Button object is a direct range reference (Sheet!Range) and I can't seem to make it just the relative cell reference. Also Button.TopLeftCell has a value of "" when I assign it to a string.

Comment: Use the `Address` property and qualify it to the other worksheet :)

Comment: Right, that might work. Thanks!

Comment: See my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got something that appears to work for me.

Here's the call for the copybutton process:

```
For Each b In OldSht.OLEObjects
    Call CopyButton(b, NewSht)
    NewSht.Rows.AutoFit
Next b
```

I added autofit because the method I'm using positions the buttons based on their distance from the top and left of the sheet in points (excel's distance measurement) which means that as it pastes the buttons into the new sheet, it might alter the target sheet row sizes (columns did not seem to be affected).

Here's the actual button copy code:

```
 Sub CopyButton(Button As OLEObject, Sht As Worksheet)
Dim NewButton As OLEObject
Dim NewButtonName As String

NewButtonName = Button.Name
Set NewButton = Button.Duplicate
NewButton.Cut

With Sht
    .Paste
    .OLEObjects(.OLEObjects.Count).Name = NewButtonName
    With .OLEObjects(NewButtonName)
        .Top = Button.Top
        .Left = Button.Left
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

This successfully copied all 200+ buttons from my source sheet to my target sheet and had them take up the same position in the new sheet. I'm not sure why TopLeftCell doesn't work, but this method works for an absolute position on the document. If you're looking for a more indirect positioning, this isn't going to work.

This means that while this does appear to work, the formatting of both sheets is integral and must be carefully managed to keep this working.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this. Copy the button, then use the relative `.Address` of the original button's `.TopLeftCell`.  The logic is: `.TopLeftCell` returns a `Range` type object, which has an `.Address` property. You can qualify that address to the `sht` parameter, like so:

```
Sub CopyButton(btn As OLEObject, sht As Worksheet)

Dim newButton As OLEObject

Set newButton = btn.Duplicate
newButton.Cut

With sht
    .Paste
    Set newButton = .OLEObjects(.OLEObjects.Count)
    newButton.TopLeftCell = .Range(btn.TopLeftCell.Address)
End With

End Sub
```

This also works, and doesn't rely on `Cut` or `Paste` at all. So, it is a little more efficient.

```
Sub CopyButton2(btn As OLEObject, sht As Worksheet)

Dim newButton As OLEObject

Set newButton = btn.Duplicate
With newButton
    .TopLeftCell = sht.Range(btn.TopLeftCell.Address)
    .Name = btn.Name
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: when I use sht.Range(btn.TopLeftCell.Address) it puts the first duplicated button in the btn worksheet instead of the sht worksheet because the range becomes "bntSheet!$btnRange". I can't seem to call the button range without getting its sheet attached to it.

Comment: `sht.Range(btn.TopLeftCell.Address)` **should** return only the *address* portion, not the sheet name. If it's returning the sheet name, I would expect a 1004 error, because that operation can't possibly be performed.  Consider revising your Q to show the code you're currentlya ttempting to use.

Comment: Is the original button (the one being duplicated) set on a `Name` range? If so (I'm not sure how you did it that way) but try: `.TopLeftCell = sht.Range(btn.TopLeftCell.Name.RefersToRange.Address)`

Comment: When I make a string and set it's value to Button.TopLeftCell.Address the string value is "$E$10" for the first button (out of ~ 120 on this first sheet). I'm really not sure why I'm getting the 1004 error when setting the new button Address. I'm now trying to set the new button topleftcell to the string value.

Comment: Is the destination sheet Protected or otherwise locked? That's a common cause of 1004 error.

Comment: - That didn't work either. Method Range failed again. Tried with TopLeftCell = String (default pull of topleftcell.address) and also tried with adding "s to the string (to make it "Address") neither worked.

Comment: no I start the process by removing all protection and locking from the workbook (since the overall process is doing this with all applicable sheets which changes from workbook to workbook and I want to make sure it doesn't impact the code).

Comment: I wish I could share the document, but security protocols at work prevent that.

Comment: I don't understand either of the points you made in the last comment.  Can you do me a favor and try to implement this (my) code in a NEW workbook?  That may help isolate the problem as having something to do with the file itself. I'm certain the method should work, because I've tested it in Excel 2010 and 2013.

Comment: You still haven't answered whether this is a NAME range.  I've asked twice about that.  If it is, how did you do that? If it is not, there is no such thing as "btnRange" and of course an invalid address will 1004 when used as an argument to the Range method, e.g., `Debug.Print Range("David").Address` will fail. So HOW does the rang evaluate to `btnRange`, as you previously mentioned in the first comment?

Comment: Trying a new sheet. When I say something like btnRange I'm referring to the range value being discussed as belonging to the button. In other words Range(Button.TopLeftCell.Address). Rather than typing it out every time I'm just saying "that range object that is pertinent to the button" aka "the button's range" aka btnRange. Sorry my shorthand is confusing. That's also what I did with my last comment "String" in this case is String = Button.TopLeftCell.Address so then "Address" refers to the value of String.

Comment: It's not helpful to not be precise :)  Also, **not** a new *sheet*, but a new *workbook*.  Close Excel completely and start with a brand new workbook. See if you can get it to work in a new file. If so, that suggests some quirk with your workbook file.

Comment: Yes, correct, new workbook. Only workbook that is open. Updating the question so I can show you results of new workbook.

Comment: Also the intended point of my string comment was to say "this is the value of the range I'm using. It is not a named range"

Comment: There is a known bug regarding ActiveX controls like these OLEObjects. That's about as much as I can possibly offer you at this point. I'm not able to replicate the error on my end, the code works exactly as it *ought* to work, and I see no reason why it should not work.  Sorry I can't be of any more assistance, but the symptoms you describe sound like a bug in the application, not the code, and as such, they're not likely to be resolved with VBA.